# Meteor subscription to get only new documents

Tags: mongodb, meteor, grounddb

Just wondering if there is a way to set my meteor subscription to load only new documents from a mongo collection, avoiding to sync deletes and updates (Since they are not relevant in the data that is shown to user).
Why I need that?   It seems anytime I do a `Meteor.subscribe` after an offline period, the WHOLE collection is sent again from server to client, while I only need the new records.

I think this happen to keep local/remote database integrity, but since my app is planned to work online/offline (I'm using also groundDB), it seems to me It will be very inefficient in terms of data usage.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a publish which sends only new documents. Like:

```
Meteor.publish('newDocumentsOnly', () => {
  let initializing = true;
  const handle = Collection.find().observeChanges({
    added: (id, fields) => {
      if (initializing) return;
      this.added('Collection', id, fields);
    }
  });
  initializing = false;
  this.ready();
  this.onStop(() => {
    handle.stop();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  It works!  Do you know if there is a way to observeChanges inside an array in the collection?  I mean, detect any time a new object is pushed into an array...

Comment: Then you should also observe `changed`. You can also do a diff manually, if you want to send only changes in array. But this becomes more complicated.